# Dudas con array en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, array

Tengo dos dudas con los array.

He definido mi array de 5 elementos así, que creo que está bien.

```
int[] th= new int[5];
```

A los elementos del array le doy los valores tal que así:

```
        if (hour == 1) {
            th[0] = 0;
            th[1] = 1;
            th[2] = 0;
            th[3] = 0;
            th[4] = 0;}
```

Tengo dos dudas:

1. ¿Habría alguna forma de definir mi array en una sola línea de código?
   Algo de este estilo: th[] = (0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
2. Además, me gustaría que mi array pudiese tomar otros valores y que el sistema escogiese al azar una de las 2 opciones
   Algo de este estilo: th[] = {(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]}

Creo que me he expresado con suficiente claridad: resumir array en una línea de código y que pueda escoger entre varias opciones.
He buscado por todos lados y no encuentro la solución a mi problema.

Gracias.

EDIT:

El problema con lo último que me planteas es que yo ya tengo esto:

switch (hour) {

```
        case 1:
            th[0] = 0;
            th[1] = 1;
            th[2] = 0;
            th[3] = 0;
            th[4] = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            th[0] = 1;
            th[1] = 1;
            th[2] = 0;
            th[3] = 0;
            th[4] = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            th[0] = 0;
            th[1] = 1;
            th[2] = 1;
            th[3] = 0;
            th[4] = 0;
            break;
        case 4:
            th[0] = 1;
            th[1] = 1;
            th[2] = 1;
            th[3] = 0;
            th[4] = 0;
            break;
        case 5:
            th[0] = 1;
            th[1] = 1;
            th[2] = 0;
            th[3] = 1;
            th[4] = 0;
            break;
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando sea el caso 1 haya varias opciones posibles y se seleccione una al azar, con el caso 2 otras varias opciones y se selecciona una al azar, lo mismo con el caso 3, con el caso 4 y con el caso 5.

Answer (score 3):

Para tu primera pregunta, la solución podría ser:

```
int[] th = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0};
```

Para la segunda no entiendo bien lo que preguntas, si es un array de dos dimensiones, o uno solo que pueda ir incrementando sus valores

Si fuera de dos dimensiones, sería;

```
//en éste caso habría tres filas, y en cada fila tres valores
int[][] nombreArray = new int[3][3];
//aquí lo declaramos y le damos los valores en la misma línea
int[][]  nombreArray = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

En éste modelo que has puesto, estarías diciendo que el array es de dos dimensiones, con dos filas y cinco columnas (recuerda que los array se empiezan a contabilizar en 0, filas 0 y 1, y columnas 0, 1, 2 ,3 y 4:

```
int[][] th = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Si lo que deseas es asignar valores aleatorios a un array, la forma podría ser:

```
  Random rd = new Random();
  int[] th = new int[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
     th[i] = rd.nextInt();
     System.out.print(th[i] + ", ");
  }
```

Si deseas tener un array con el mismo nombre y distintos valores, puedes crear un método donde puedas elegir tu mismo en array solicitando el que deseas:

```
  //llamas al método y le indicas que array deseas a voluntad
  int[] th = metodoSeleccionarArray(1)

  //creas el método que selecciona el array en función del número que le indiques
  private int[] metodoSeleccionarArray(int array){
      if (array == 1){
          int[] th = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
      }
      else if (array == 2){
          int[] th = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
      }
      return th;
  }
```

Si deseas seleccionar el array de forma aleatoria, solo tienes que poner antes de la llamada la método:

```
Random r = new Random();
//Generar valores entre 1 y 2.
int valorArray = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
```

En la llamada al método:

```
int[] th = metodoSeleccionarArray(valorArray);
```

EDITADO:

A ver, es que no llego a entenderte del todo cuando dices que en cada case necesitas que haya varias opciones cuando para las opciones supongo que hayas creado los case. Veamos:

Creas una nueva Clase o método, yo lo hice con una clase:

```
//En esta clase hay tres Arrays diferentes, podrías poner más o menos
class GenerarArray {
public int[] metodoSeleccionarArray(int n){
    int[] th = new int[5];
    if (n == 1){
        th[0] = 0; th[1] = 1; th[2] = 0; th[3] = 0; th[4] = 0;
    }
    else if (n == 2){
        th[0] = 0; th[1] = 0; th[2] = 0; th[3] = 1; th[4] = 0;
    }
    else if (n == 3){
        th[0] = 1; th[1] = 0; th[2] = 0; th[3] = 0; th[4] = 0;
    }
    return th;
}
```

}

Desde el método main, o desde donde deseas llamarlo que tienes el switch:

```
    //Ahora lo que hacemos, es, que en función del case que elijas, se genere un número aleatorio entre 1 y 3, y ese número elija un array al azar de la clase donde están generados
    GenerarArray miArray = new GenerarArray();
    int nArray = 0;
    int[] thRes = new int[5];
    
    switch (hour) {
        case 1:
            Random r1 = new Random();
            nArray = r1.nextInt(3) + 1;  
            thRes = miArray.metodoSeleccionarArray(nArray);
            break;
        case 2:
            Random r2 = new Random();
            nArray = r2.nextInt(3) + 1;  
            thRes = miArray.metodoSeleccionarArray(nArray);
            break;
        case 3:
            Random r3 = new Random();
            nArray = r3.nextInt(3) + 1;  
            thRes = miArray.metodoSeleccionarArray(nArray);
            break;
        case 4:
            Random r4 = new Random();
            nArray = r4.nextInt(3) + 1;  
            thRes = miArray.metodoSeleccionarArray(nArray);
            break;
        case 5:
            Random r5 = new Random();
            nArray = r5.nextInt(3) + 1;  
            thRes = miArray.metodoSeleccionarArray(nArray);
            break;
    }
```

Ahora ya te habría generado ese Array en thRes.

Comment: No sé si es que no me he expresado bien. Yo no quiero que se le asignen valores aleatorios al array. Quiero que se selecciones aleatoriamente una de las opciones que YO doy. Quiero que el array sea {1,0,0,0,0} o {0,1,0,0,0}, no más. Y quiero ponerlo todo en pocas líneas, para optimizar.

Comment: Edito mi post principal.

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré y te comento :)

Comment: Editada de nuevo, a ver si te sirve ahora, un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha servido de gran ayuda. Era más o menos lo que necesitaba. Una única duda, aquí nArray = r4.nextInt(3) + 1;  por qué hay un "3" en el paréntesis porque hay 3 opciones? En caso de que en mi clase GenerarArray hubiera solo 2 opciones tendría que poner un "2"?

Comment: Eso mismo, date cuenta que en la clase validamos que si es un 1, nos retorne un array, si es un 2, otro distinto. El parámetro del random es para generar un número menor, por lo tanto si ponemos un 3, genera aleatorios entre 0 y 2. Nosotros se sumamos 1, para que así el aleatorio sea entre 0 + 1 y 2 + 1. Si agregas otro array en los if, en lugar de un 3, tendrías que poner un 4, y si como bien dices, quitas un Array de la clase, tendrías que poner un 2